# telescoping series and its sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Write $S=\sum\limits_{n=8}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$ as a telescoping series and find its sum.

$S_N =  $

$S =  $

I found for the first one to be $\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{N-1}$ but it says it's incorrect.

Comment: The typical term is $1/(k-1)-1/k$.

Comment: @user96246, you have a good idea but you need to consider the endpoints of the sum.

Comment: You're almost correct:
$$
-\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\sum_{n=8}^\infty\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=8}^N\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=8}^N\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{N}=\frac{1}{7}$$